# Spring Boot and Spring Data MongoDB: hiding fields in a ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot together with the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb package.

I have successfully created a method to return account information for my app:

```
public Account queryAccountInfo(String userId) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId));
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Account.class);
}
```

Now, this returns all the information in the Account class which is a custom class I have created:

```
    public class Account {

        public Account(){}


        @Id
        private String id;
        private String email;
        private String token; 
}
```

Now, Spring will return the entire Account object in a ResponseBody object so it will create a JSON similar to this:

```
{
  "id": "1234567890",
  "email": "Google@google.com",
  "token": "XXX-XXX-XXX"}
```

I don't want it to return the "token" as that is sensitive information. How can I get Spring to not return the "token" field but return everything else?

I'm sure there is a Spring annotation that will allow me to do this but I cannot seem to find it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/package-frame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method should be:

```
query.fields().exclude("token");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem is the lack of separation of mongodb bean objects and objects used in your API. While this is not necessary during the PoC phase of your project, when you bump into issues like this, you should add a second set of beans used for communication and map between the objects used for spring-data-mongo.

Comment: Yuk, that thinking is so 1999! You have your view model, your dto, and your dad. I'll stick to a dictionary any day.

Comment: It is best practice for a reason. The 2 data models might look very similar, but they are actually different, and this difference is what otherwise would result in nasty hacks (think of the random `if()` here and there). This is how you fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalente **Mongo Query**

**db.account.aggregate({$project:{email:1}})**

> Código Kotlin:

```
package com.integracion.controller
import com.integracion.modelo.Account

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.*
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query

@RestController
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = arrayOf(AccountRepository::class))

class InicioController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var accountRepository: AccountRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var query: MongoTemplate

@GetMapping("v2/filtro")
    //Query es la libreria import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query
    fun filtro (q: Query): Document {
        /*
           // Equivalente en MongoDB //
              db.account.find({},{email:1})
           //Manera simple pero devulve los excluidos con campos vacios null ""
        q.fields().include("email").exclude("token");
        var consulta : List<Account> = query.find(q,Account::class.java)*/


// =) 

        /* //Equivalente en MongoDB//
        db.account.aggregate({$project:{email:1}}) */


        var p: ProjectionOperation = Aggregation.project("email")
        var a: Aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(p)
        var resultado: Document = query.aggregate(a,"account",Account::class.java).rawResults

        return resultado
    }
}
```